# How do i change the background foreground and border color in WPF when hovering with my mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to change the color of the button in my WPF project so that when you're hovering over with your mouse.
The default should be:

```
background: #00000f
foreground: #77dff1
border: #77dff1
```

The desired output should be:

```
background: #77dff1
foreground: #FFFFFF
border: #FFFFFF
```

I think this is correct but I have no idea why it's only executing the middle setter command

```
<Window x:Class="introducereDAC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:introducereDAC"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Divide et Impera" Height="450" Width="800" Background="#FF00000F">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Introducere DEI (curent)" Margin="15" Width="177" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed" Foreground="#505054"/>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Content="Introducere DEI" Width="200" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000f"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#77dff1"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#77dff1"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#77dff1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Content="DEI Iterativ" Width="200" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Content="Probleme DEI" Width="200" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `middle setter command`? Only foreground color is changing?

Comment: yes, only the foreground is changing

Comment: Your code is correct, check if you have given a background color value inline inside the `<button>` tag itself as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a control template in your style:

```xml
<Button Content="Introducere DEI" Width="200" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000f"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#77dff1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#77dff1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#77dff1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Result on mouse over:

[image]